# Вывод результатов запроса в файл

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно вывести данные некоего справочника в текстовый файл (просто все записи).

У справочника есть табличная часть "предшественники" и их тоже надо вывести в файл.

Текст выводится при помощи следующих вызовов:

```
Текст = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
Текст.УстановитьТекст(МойТекст);
Текст.Записать("C:\Users\DP118M\Desktop\daily stuff\dottest.txt",КодировкаТекста.UTF8);
```

Непонятно, как мне сделать запрос вроде (вроде записи = "SELECT * FROM Справочник"), а потом сделать нечто подобное:

```
МойТекст = "digraph G {" & НоваяСтрока
Для каждого Запись Из Записи     
   Для каждого Предшественник Из Запись.Предшественники     
   Цикл          
      МойТекст = МойТекст & Предшественник.Код & " -> " & Запись.Код & НоваяСтрока;     
   КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла
МойТекст = МойТекст & "}" & НоваяСтрока
```

Вопрос: Каким образом надо делать запрос, чтобы получить Записи в таком виде?

Я пытался сделать вот это:

```
&НаСервереБезКонтекста
Функция КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот()
     Результат = Справочники.Концепция.Выбрать();
     Возврат Результат; // Здесь вылетает ошибка
КонецФункции

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ExportToDot(Команда)
     Сообщить("Это тест, dot");

 Цели = КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот();

 Сообщить("Цели:" + Цели);

 Текст = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
 Текст.УстановитьТекст("digraph d { A -> B } фис");
 Текст.Записать("C:\Users\DP118M\Desktop\daily stuff\dottest.txt",КодировкаТекста.UTF8);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Но при попытке передать на клиент результат запроса Справочники.Концепция.Выбрать() вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
{Справочник.Концепция.Форма.ФормаСписка.Форма(11)}: Fehler beim Aufrufen einer Kontextmethode (КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот)
      Цели = КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот();
da:
Fehler beim Übertragen von Daten zwischen dem Client und dem Server. Wert vom nicht zulässigen Typ.
da:
Fehler beim Transformieren der XDTO-Daten:
Schreiben des Eigenschaftswertes 'ret'
     Formular:Element
     Name: { v8.1c.ru/8.2/managed-app... »»
da:
Fehler beim Typenanzeigen:
Anzeige für den Typ 'СправочникВыборка.Концепция' nicht vorhanden
```

Перевожу: Ошибка при вызове контекстного метода (КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот) [...] Ошибка при передаче
данных между клиентом и сервером. Значение имеет неправильный тип. Ошибка при преобразовании данных XDTO.

Заранее спасибо

Дмитрий

Comment: Это что за язык 0о
а пардон.. 1с

Comment: Это встроенный язык "1С:Предприятие 8.2", работающий под немецкоязычной семеркой. Сладкая парочка :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот это работает:

```
&НаСервере
Функция КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот()
    Перем СодержимоеФайла;
    Перем Ярлык;
    Перем ОформлениеУзла;

    Выборка = Справочники.Концепция.Выбрать();

    ТекстовыйДокумент = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;

[...]

    Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл
[...]   
        ТекстовыйДокумент.ДобавитьСтроку(Выборка.Код);
[...]           
    КонецЦикла;

    Возврат ТекстовыйДокумент;
КонецФункции

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ExportToDot(Команда)  
    ТекстовыйДокумент = КонцепцияДляЭкспортаВДот();

ТекстовыйДокумент.Записать("concept.dot",КодировкаТекста.UTF8);
КонецПроцедуры
```